# state transition error in django-fsm and resetting the current state to default

Tags: django, django-fsm

I have an Order model which has a field status which has choices -> NEW (default), PENDING(PDG), DISPATCHED(DSP), COMPLETED(CMP), CANCELLED(CLD)

models.py

```
class Order(Address, TimeStampedUUIDModel):

    status = FSMField(
        max_length=25,
        choices=constants.STATUS_CHOICES,
        default=constants.NEW,
    )

    @transition(field=status, source=constants.NEW, target=constants.PDG)
    def to_pending(self):
        self.status = constants.PDG


    @transition(field=status, source=constants.PDG, target=constants.DSP)
    def to_dispatched(self):
        self.status = constants.DSP


    @transition(field=status, source=constants.DSP, target=constants.CMP)
    def to_completed(self):
        self.status = constants.CMP


    @transition(
        field=status,
        source=[constants.NEW, constants.PDG, constants.DSP],
        target=constants.CLD,
    )
    def to_cancel(self):
        self.status = constants.CLD
```

serializers.py

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Order
        fields = "__all__"
        read_only_fields = [--all fields except status--]

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        status = validated_data.pop("status", None)
        agent =  self.context['request'].user
        instance = services.status_function(status, instance, agent)
        return instance
```

In the below services file I'm simultaneously trying to create an order activity object to track changes in Order object.

services.py

```
def status_function(status, instance, agent):
    if status is not None:
        switcher = {
            constants.PDG : instance.to_pending,
            constants.DSP : instance.to_dispatched,
            constants.CMP : instance.to_completed,
            constants.CLD : instance.to_cancel
        }
        func = switcher.get(status, None)
        try:
            func()
            models.OrderActivity.objects.create(
                event_name=status,
                order = instance,
                event = f"Order {status}",
                agent = agent,
                time = instance.modified_at
            )
        except TransitionNotAllowed :
            print("Exception Caught")
            raise exceptions.BadRequest([{"error": "Transition not allowed"}])

    return instance
```

constants.py

```
from extended_choices import Choices

## Order Status
NEW, NEW_ = "NEW", "NEW"
PDG, PDG_ = "PDG", "PENDING"
DSP, DSP_ = "DSP", "DISPATCHED"
CMP, CMP_ = "CMP", "COMPLETED"
CLD, CLD_ = "CLD", "CANCELLED"

STATUS_CHOICES = ( 
    (NEW, NEW_), 
    (PDG, PDG_), 
    (DSP, DSP_), 
    (CMP, CMP_),
    (CLD, CLD_),
)
```

My problem is that transitions other than NEW -> PDG, NEW -> CLD, and PDG -> CLD are raising an exception and also reverting the status of Order object to NEW which should not happen.
Thanks in advance !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove assignment from every transition function

Change every transition function to:

```
    def to_completed(self):
            return
```

Since the states are changed by calling the function themselves. but not changed in database. So we only need to save the instance itself.
Below func() in services.py put

`instance.save()`